# How to fix the margin in CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container header which is flex activated.

Inside it are two more child containers - #nav-bar (contains nav links)and #header-img (contains logo).
The issue comes when I want to put the nav-links right to the bottom their box, which I'm unable to as the box size is being determined by the logo.

Basically - the 'Home' 'Features' 'Contact us' should touch the lower border.
I have tried all flex properties however cannot figure it out.

Can someone help?

```css
#header{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#nav-bar{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  align-content:flex-end;
}
.nav-link{
  padding-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img id="header-img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g2bJbHNX/email-logo-AUM.png" width=25% height=25%>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="/home.come">Home</p>
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="#summary-video">Features</p>
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="/contactus.com">Contact us</a></p>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: I dont understand how you want the result to be, can u add an illustration?

Comment: Hi Omri
I wanted the home, features and contact us to touch the bottom of their border boxes. 
The answer has been given by @baro.
I am unable to attach a pic to show you how I wanted it, but if you check out his solution, you'll understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you were trying to achieve? If so, the property you need is `align-self` (in addition to removing the default paragraph `p` bottom margin).

```css
#header{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#nav-bar{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  align-content:flex-end;
}
.nav-link {
  padding-left:25px;
  
  margin-bottom:0px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img id="header-img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g2bJbHNX/email-logo-AUM.png" width=25% height=25%>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="/home.come">Home</p>
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="#summary-video">Features</p>
    <p class="nav-link"><a href="/contactus.com">Contact us</a></p>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Oh yes! This worked! 
I had never heard of this tag, going to look this up now. Thank you buddy!